# is there a way to know when an html element moves

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to know when an html element moves within its parent, so that I can position other elements accordingly. The reasons the element can move is that its content changes, or some other elements, which may not be its descendants, are added or moved.
So far, the only solution I can think of is to use a MutationObserver at the common ancestor level, and then compare every location of every element to its memorised position.
But that seems overkill to me....
Any other idea?
(I am using React so an existing React Hook would do the job, but I can live with plain JS)

Comment: Please provide your code. When the content will change? Can't you add a function in the step changing the content?